# Find if matrix is diagonally dominant or not in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find if the matrix is diagonally dominant or not.
I have developed a code which as follows.

```
sum=0
def isDiagonallyDominantMatrix(A):
    global sum
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A)):
            sum=sum+abs(A[i][j])
            diag=abs(A[i][i])
            non_diag=sum-diag
            if((diag<non_diag)):
                return 0
    return 1
A=[[7,2,1],[1,7,2],[1,2,7]]
if(isDiagonallyDominantMatrix(A)):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

whenever I run the above code, 'no' is displayed although the A matrix is diagonally dominant.can you plz help where I am making a mistake

Answer (score 3):

After the examples in Wikipedia about what is Diagonally dominant matrix ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix#Examples)), why are you having `sum` global? `sum` needs to be computed only for each row:

```
A=[[7,2,1],
   [1,7,2],
   [1,2,7]]

def isDiagonallyDominantMatrix(A):
    for i, row in enumerate(A):
        s = sum(abs(v) for j, v in enumerate(row) if i != j)
        if s > abs(row[i]):
            return False
    return True

if(isDiagonallyDominantMatrix(A)):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

This prints:

```
yes
```

Note: Don't use `0` or `1` for indicating `False` or `True`. Python has constants for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative approach using numpy to separate the matrix from its diagonal and compare (might be faster for larger matrices):

```
A = [[7,2,1],
     [1,7,2],
     [1,2,7]]

def is_diagonal(A):
    A = np.abs(np.asarray(A))  # converts lists to numpy arrays
    diagonal = np.diag(A)  # [7, 7, 7]
    others = A - np.diag(diagonal)  # matrix 'A' but with zeros along the diagonal
    return np.all(diagonal >= others.sum(axis=1))

is_diagonal(A)
True
```

The `return np.all(...)` line in the function tests whether each element that you pulled from the diagonal of the matrix is greater than or equal to the sum of the remaining elements in the row. If it is for *all* rows, it returns true. If it is false for *any* row, it returns false.

Note that when we convert the input to a numpy array, we take its absolute value too. This is because [we need the absolute value for our sum to say whether the matrix is diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix#Examples).

A bit more concisely:

```
def is_diagonal(A):
    A = np.abs(np.asarray(A))
    return np.all(np.diag(A) >= A.sum(axis=1) / 2)
```

This second option works because in order for it to be true that *any* single element in the row is greater than or equal to the sum of all the *other* elements, it *must* be true that the single element is greater than or equal to half of the sum of *all* elements.

Comment: @kunalghate if something worked for you, you can thank the author by up-voting their answer or marking it as "accepted" (once you have the reputation necessary).